# Why android emulator close itself during strat up

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I run android emulator from eclipse. After some time it close itself without any action from my side? What is a reason of that and how improve it?

Comment: I think it is not this. I increase RAM in my VM (1 GB) and still nothing (i try launch 384 MG android emulator)